# jQuery: Get the cursor position of text in input without browser specific code?

Tags: jquery, input, cursor-position

Is there any way in jQuery to get the current cursor-position in an text input without doing ugly browser specific code?

Like in:

```
<input id="myTextInput" type="text" value="some text" >
```

the cursor being after the "x" of "some text", I can get "8"?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-caret-position-within-an-text-input-field

Comment: Sorry, the input field was not showing in the beginning. That should tell what I want.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can't do this without *some* browser specific code, since they implement text select ranged slightly differently.  However, there are plugins that abstract this away.  For exactly what you're after, there's the [jQuery Caret (jCaret) plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/caret/).

For your code to get the position you could do something like this:

```
$("#myTextInput").bind("keydown keypress mousemove", function() {
  alert("Current position: " + $(this).caret().start);
});
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/FCWrE/).

Comment: This Jquery Caret link http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCaret is down.

Comment: Link to the jCaret project at Google Code [http://code.google.com/p/jcaret](http://code.google.com/p/jcaret)

Comment: @nickcraver Not working on my code. Do I need to add another source like <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script> ?

Comment: Yeah, you need jQuery.

Comment: .start is undefined in ie11.  You need to use .begin

Comment: I believe the link is now: https://bitbucket.org/accursoft/caret/src

Answer (score 18):

Using the syntax `text_element.selectionStart` we can get the starting position of the selection of a text in terms of the index of the first character of the selected text in the `text_element.value` and in case we want to get the same of the last character in the selection we have to use `text_element.selectionEnd`.

Use it as follows:

```
<input type=text id=t1 value=abcd>
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('t1').selectionStart)">check position</button>
```

I'm giving you the [**fiddle_demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U7Mgw/35/)

Comment: Why do you bother putting el.value into var val? Abbreviating such an explicit term to only use it once seems just to confuse otherwise nice code (I've not run it yet :)

Comment: @LeeGee true and hence reduced the code.

Comment: Great solution! It doesn't work in IE8, but who cares!

Answer (score 16):

A warning about the Jquery Caret plugin.

It will conflict with the [Masked Input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) (or vice versa).  Fortunately the Masked Input plugin includes a caret() function of its own, which you can use very similarly to the Caret plugin for your basic needs - $(element).caret().begin or .end

Comment: Also, the jsfiddle numbers do not look correct in the case where one might press the down/up keys.  The cursor swings to the end of the text box but the value is not representative of such moves to the start/end of the input.

Answer (score 7):

just came across while browsing, might help you **[`javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea`](http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea)**. You can use it for textbox also.

Comment: Unfortunately this website is no longer accessible. Do you remember what the implementation involved?