# How to insert a div into the content of another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do i insert a div inside the content of another content-editable div? The parent div is a content-editable one and its contains string content. I want to insert another content-editable div when i type '@' at the cursor position.

for example,

```
 <div id="target" class="text-area" contenteditable='true'>This text can be anything... how to insert a div when i type start typing @... </div>
```

I want to insert another div when i type '@'? How can i achieve this?

Here is what i tried out [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/uyufiw/25/edit)

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to work for me.  I just added in a $(this).append(...)

```
$("#target").keydown(function(e) {

//  console.log(e, String.fromCharCode(e.which));

  if(e.which === 50 && e.shiftKey === true ){
      if(flag === true){
        flag = false;      
        return;
      }      
      flag = true;
    $(this).append('<div id="target2" contenteditable="true">New Div</div>');
      //console.log($('#target'),$('#target').prop('selectionStart'));
    } 
});
```

Comment: Using append() will not position the div at the cursor point... The new div will be appended as a childnode rather than appending at the cursor position... If i type '@' anywhere in between the string, i want the new div to be appended at the cursor position. Is there a way ??

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to detect the keydown event on the '@' character and then place an absolutely positioned div at the current cursor location.

Getting the cursor position is a decent bit of code. Luckily, someone already wrote it. The code is as follows:

```
function getTextAreaXandY() {



   // Don't do anything if key pressed is left arrow
    if (e.which == 37) return;     

    // Save selection start
    var selection = $(this).getSelection();
    var index = selection.start;

    // Copy text to div
    $(this).blur();
    $("div").text($(this).val());

    // Get current character
    $(this).setSelection(index, index + 1);
    currentcharacter = $(this).getSelection().text;

    // Get previous character
    $(this).setSelection(index - 1, index)
    previouscharacter = $(this).getSelection().text;

    var start, endchar;
    var end = 0;
    var range = rangy.createRange();

    // If current or previous character is a space or a line break, find the next word and wrap it in a span
    var linebreak = previouscharacter.match(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm) == undefined ? false : true;

    if (previouscharacter == ' ' || currentcharacter == ' ' || linebreak) {
        i = index + 1; // Start at the end of the current space        
        while (endchar != ' ' && end < $(this).val().length) {
            i++;
            $(this).setSelection(i, i + 1)
            var sel = $(this).getSelection();
            endchar = sel.text;
            end = sel.start;
        }

        range.setStart($("div")[0].childNodes[0], index);
        range.setEnd($("div")[0].childNodes[0], end);
        var nextword = range.toHtml();
        range.deleteContents();
        var position = $("<span id='nextword'>" + nextword + "</span>")[0];
        range.insertNode(position);
        var nextwordtop = $("#nextword").position().top;
    }

    // Insert `#caret` at the position of the caret
    range.setStart($("div")[0].childNodes[0], index);
    var caret = $("<span id='caret'></span>")[0];
    range.insertNode(caret);
    var carettop = $("#caret").position().top;

    // If preceding character is a space, wrap it in a span
    if (previouscharacter == ' ') {
        range.setStart($("div")[0].childNodes[0], index - 1);
        range.setEnd($("div")[0].childNodes[0], index);
        var prevchar = $("<span id='prevchar'></span>")[0];
        range.insertNode(prevchar);
        var prevchartop = $("#prevchar").position().top;
    }

    // Set textarea selection back to selection start
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).setSelection(index, selection.end);

    // If the top value of the previous character span is not equal to the top value of the next word,
    // there must have been some wrapping going on, the previous character was a space, so the wrapping
    // would have occured after this space, its safe to assume that the left and top value of `#nextword`
    // indicate the caret position
    if (prevchartop != undefined && prevchartop != nextwordtop) {
        $("label").text('X: ' + $("#nextword").position().left + 'px, Y: ' + $("#nextword").position().top);
        $('ul').css('left', ($("#nextword").position().left) + 'px');
        $('ul').css('top', ($("#nextword").position().top + 13) + 'px');
    }
    // if not, then there was no wrapping, we can take the left and the top value from `#caret`    
    else {
        $("label").text('X: ' + $("#caret").position().left + 'px, Y: ' + $("#caret").position().top);
        $('ul').css('left', ($("#caret").position().left) + 'px');
        $('ul').css('top', ($("#caret").position().top + 14) + 'px');
    }

    $('ul').css('display', 'block');
}

$("textarea").click(getTextAreaXandY);
$("textarea").keyup(getTextAreaXandY);
```

Their fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wrzPk/55/), and it was written in response to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212871/get-the-offset-position-of-the-caret-in-a-textarea-in-pixels?lq=1)

The fiddle includes placing a new div at the current cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the onKeyDown event listener.
Binding the keydown event to div which id equal to target.

Hope this is helpful for you.
http://jsbin.com/ilikay/4/edit

Answer (score -1):

Finally had a way to reach it... This is how i did it ...

1. Get the string index at the cursor position in the textarea by using selectionStart
2. slice the string from index 0 to the cursor position
3. Insert it into a span (since span has multiple border boxes)
4. Get the dimensions of the border box using element.getClientRects() relative to the view port. (here is the [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getClientRects))
5. Calculate the top and left and feed it to the dropdown

This works in all latest browsers. haven't tested at old ones

Here is [Working bin](http://jsbin.com/uyufiw/39/edit)

Comment: May i know why is the down voting ...?