# locate text string in textarea based on GET and move cursor to that text

Tags: jquery

The textarea in my form, id="Fulltext", is fed by database with many chapters of a book.
When the user clicks a link above the text area,
`<a href="samePage.php?chap=Chapter 5" id="Chapter 5">Chapter 5</a>`, I would like the cursor to move inside the textarea and position itself in front of the text, 'Chapter 5'.
Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible.  On an unrelated note, `id` cannot have spaces.

Comment: You're right and since I'm using the GET to identify the text I'm looking for, I don't need the id anyway;
and I used a hash but this page draws in additional information from a page in an iframe and it needs to have the actual link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/deg6j/

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectText(text)
        {
            var textArea = $('#Fulltext');
            var index = textArea.text().search(text);
            textArea.caretTo(index);      
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id='Fulltext' rows=10>
    Chapter 1
    This is a lot of text...

    Chapter 2
    More more more

    Chapter 3
    More dsa less
</textarea>
    <a href="#" onclick="selectText('Chapter 2')">Chapter 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
new function($) {
  // Behind the scenes method deals with browser
    // idiosyncrasies and such
    $.caretTo = function (el, index) {
        if (el.createTextRange) { 
            var range = el.createTextRange(); 
            range.move("character", index); 
            range.select(); 
        } else if (el.selectionStart != null) { 
            el.focus(); 
            el.setSelectionRange(index, index); 
        }
    };

    // The following methods are queued under fx for more
    // flexibility when combining with $.fn.delay() and
    // jQuery effects.

    // Set caret to a particular index
    $.fn.caretTo = function (index, offset) {
        return this.queue(function (next) {
            if (isNaN(index)) {
                var i = $(this).val().indexOf(index);

                if (offset === true) {
                    i += index.length;
                } else if (offset) {
                    i += offset;
                }

                $.caretTo(this, i);
            } else {
                $.caretTo(this, index);
            }

            next();
        });
    };
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: Wow, that looks nice. Let me scope this out and get back to you in a bit. Thanks.

Comment: absolutely, so you know the javascript part is inside a document.ready in jquery.

Comment: Your fiddle works really well. I'll tweak around and apply it more. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for that. Obviously I'm new-ish to jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you can.

Assuming that you can identify by text where the chapter starts you can do so with [jQuery caret plugin](http://www.jquery-plugin.buss.hk/my-plugins/jquery-caret-plugin).

Check answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085312/jquery-get-the-cursor-position-of-text-in-input-without-browser-specific-code) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area) questions.

Plus, you might want to bind a javascript function in the chapter anchor.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I had seen one but not the other. Appreciate your thoughts.