# Get position of the cursor in the <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried looking at many stackoverflow discussions on how to get cursor position on a click on an input box (but many dealt with getting highlighted position using caret instead) - but nothing seems to be working for my very simple requirement.

All I want is a function which, when a mouse is clicked on an  will return the position of cursor (in terms of character count from beginning) - please note that by position I mean the character position.

*when you click somewhere on an editable input box with some text on it, I want to get the position (in terms of character count from beginning) of cursor after this click - so that I could remember this for a future click(for some specific UI requirement). –*

Is there a jQuery (or javascript) function that would do? Any workarounds are welcome too.

Thanks

EDIT-
some people are directing me to other posts - but please note that I could not use jQuery Caret or any other plug-in.  All I got is jQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Get the cursor position of text in input without browser specific code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085312/jquery-get-the-cursor-position-of-text-in-input-without-browser-specific-code)

Comment: The click is the caret position, that's the only way to get the # of where it is located. They are one in the same.

Comment: Check out [this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1909997/2038227)

Comment: Let's clarify this, are you looking for the mouse cursor's position?

Comment: @Derija93 - when you click somewhere on an editable input box with some text on it, I want to get the position of cursor after this click - so that I could remember its position (for some specific UI requirement).

Comment: @TravisO that answer requires jQuery Caret Plugin - I cant use any plugins for jQuery - corporate limitation. Only jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: Why not copy the code of the jQuery Caret plugin into your own source code to make it available? If there is such a great difficulty to embed external resources...

Comment: Because I dont know the licensing and other requirements that might be involved in using the source of such plug-in.

Comment: Check this article out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085312/jquery-get-the-cursor-position-of-text-in-input-without-browser-specific-code

Comment: This might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-within-an-text-input-field

Comment: @Tintin, Check the 2nd solution(I have given).

Answer (score 3):

***Got the solution***.
Try the following code **with verified result**-

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function f1(el) {
    var val = el.value;
    alert(val.slice(0, el.selectionStart).length);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type=text id=t1 value=abcd>
    <button onclick="f1(document.getElementById('t1'))">check position</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm giving you the [**fiddle_demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh38/U7Mgw/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Assume HTML:

```
<input id="target" />
```

The following code gives you the mouse cursor's coordinates:

```
$('#target').click(function(jqEvt){
    console.log('Coordinates within textbox', jqEvt.offsetX, jqEvt.offsetY);
    console.log('Global coordinates', jqEvt.clientX, jqEvt.clientY);
});
```

See [jQuery.Event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: What do I do with coordinates? I need the character count. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in an `<input type=image/>`

When you use the `<input type=image/>` tag, you are telling the browser to submit the x and y coordinates where the image was clicked. This allows you to add image map type functionality to your forms.

Comment: But I dont need coordinates? I need the character count. Thanks.

Comment: @Tintin What ? **Get position of the cursor in the <input>** and **All I want is a function which, when a mouse is clicked on an will return the position of cursor - please note that by position I mean the character position**  I'm not feeling good anymore ...

Comment: Sorry if it mislead - when you click somewhere on an editable input box with some text on it, I want to get the character position (count from beginning) of cursor after this click - so that I could remember its position (for some specific UI requirement). –