# is there any way to catch space in jQuery

Tags: jquery

can you please tell me how to catch space in textfield .I block all special character .But I need if user click add space button it don't show alert but it wrap the text mean not allowed space.

```
  $(document).on( "keyup", ".caseName_h",function() {
    alert("hh"+$(this).val().contains(" "));
    if($(this).val()==" "){
   alert("hh");
    }
if(/[^\w]/g.test($(this).val())) {

    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\w]/g, ""));

    PG_alert('Special characters not allowed!');

}
});
```

Comment: where is the add space button comes from

Comment: how will one know whether that button is pressed

Comment: I want to check on textfield.

Comment: check on browser (key board space button)

Comment: example nan jy ..result : nanjy without  alert

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859170/how-to-use-jquery-to-prevent-the-space-key-from-entering-a-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are always ways. Try this

```
$('.caseName_h').keyup(function(e){
    $(this).val($(this).val.replace(/\s/g,''));
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
        PG_alert('Special characters not allowed!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".caseName_h", function (e) {
    //IE does not pass event
    e = e|| window.event;
    //32 is space key code
    var keyCOde = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode
    if (keyCode == 32) { 
       //DO stuff here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your string on spaces by using the indexof command

```
var str = $(this).val(); if(str.indexof(" ") >=0){alert('spaces');}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code checks if space is pressed

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#txtChar').keydown(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 32) { 
alert('space')
}
});
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hatefull/D3rm8/)